# TSQL: Dates that lie between (intersect) from and to date?

Tags: t-sql

Can someone give me the tsql to find also the dates that lie inside the give from and to date.

```
select * from empc where
DateFrom >= p_todate AND DateTo <= p_todate
```

What I mean is that dates in between should also be captured (I do not want to use BETWEEN syntax)

please help

Comment: "Intersect" and "lie between" do not mean the same thing.  Which are you looking for?

Comment: You should change comparison to >= and <, because of half-open intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to select all ranges that intersect the given range:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    empc
WHERE   DateFrom <= p_todate
        AND DateTo >= p_fromdate
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use between:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    empc
WHERE   DateFrom BETWEEN p_fromdate AND p_todate
```

This gives you an inclusive range.

Comment: Downvote's a little harsh, considering I added this answer before the note about not wanting between...